# How to get NSURL leading to gallery image?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

in my app im using UIImagePickerController to pick an image. i want to get a NSURL leading to that image. 
in "didFinishPickingImage" method i tried using "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" and "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL" properties like some threads in stackoverflow suggested, however they both returned NULL as url.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773635/nsurl-of-uiimage-from-uiimagepickercontroller-returns-null) thread talked about something similar - however they discuss getting the image itself and not the URL, and i couldnt quite understand how to end up with a NSURL leading to my gallery image.

this is my current code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
                              didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    NSURL *imageUrl = [editingInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    NSString *stringFromURL = [imageUrl absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"%@", stringFromURL);  // this shows i do get (null)

    // ....
}
```

Thank you for your time!