# iPhone Image Loading in Photos Application

Tags: iphone

I am not sure if this is the right forum for asking this question, but I googled "questions related to iPhone" and the first page had SO from top to bottom. So here goes.

When I open the Photos Application in iPhone (3GS, 4 and 5 all running iOS 5.0) and open an image, first a blurred image appears for a fraction of a second, which clears up into the actual picture. My question is, does the Photo application have a low resolution copy of the high res images which it displays while the image is being loaded, OR does it generate a low res image on the fly before going on to load the high res image.

I am writing an application to browse through the photos, and need to know which is the best approach. That is the purpose behind this question.

Comment: When you downvote, please specify a reason as well. It will help put things in perspective and will also make sure that the problem is not repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is using ALAsset **thumbnail** . If you have concerns with image clarity, then go with ALAsset **fullResolutionImage**

Here are some details that you must read before going to start developing an photos application.

An instance of **[ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** provides access to the videos and photos that are under the control of the Photos application.

An **[ALAsset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** object represents a photo or a video managed by the Photo application.

There are different ALAsset **Accessing Representations**

**1.thumbnail**

Returns a thumbnail representation of the asset.

```
- (CGImageRef)thumbnail
```

**2.aspectRatioThumbnail**

Returns an aspect ratio thumbnail of the asset.

```
- (CGImageRef)aspectRatioThumbnail
```

**3.defaultRepresentation**

Returns an asset representation object for the default representation.

```
- (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation
```

**4.representationForUTI:**

Returns an an asset representation object for a given representation UTI.

```
- (ALAssetRepresentation *)representationForUTI:(NSString *)representationUTI
```

An **[ALAssetRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** object encapsulates one of the representations of a given **ALAsset** object.

**1.CGImageWithOptions**:

Returns a full resolution CGImage of the representation.

```
- (CGImageRef)CGImageWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
```

**2.fullResolutionImage**

Returns a CGImage representation of the asset.

```
- (CGImageRef)fullResolutionImage
```

**3.fullScreenImage**

Returns a CGImage of the representation that is appropriate for displaying full screen.

```
- (CGImageRef)fullScreenImage
```

**[Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721762/how-to-convert-image-path-to-uiimage-using-alassetslibrary/11723156#11723156)**